# What does "A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type" mean?

Tags: c#, linq, types, expression

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
        con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=OCS-MXL930055N\\;Initial           Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand

        con.Open("Select * from ShoppingList", con);

        con.Close("Select * from ShoppingList", con);
    }
}
```

And these are the lines I am having problems with:

```
con.Open("Select * from ShoppingList", con)();

con.Close("Select * from ShoppingList", con)();
```

Any help with what they mean? I'm not too sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It means that the compiler needs to know somehow you're trying to initialize a new instance (or several instances) of a type. In your case add parentheses to: `SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();` Notice the brackets?

Answer (score 5):

Your statement:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
```

should be :

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ShoppingList");
```

Later when you are opening and closing the connection, just remove the parameters, these parameters are required for `SqlCommand` constructor.

You may have your code like:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=OCS-MXL930055N\\;Initial Catalog=sample;Integrated Security=True"))
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ShoppingList", con))
{
    //.. code to execute command
}
```

Read about basic C#, constructors and [ADO.Net Examples on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dw70f090%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

C# isn't ruby you need to make your intent known. There are 3 ways to instantiate an object, all using the `new` operator::
e.g.

```
var myObj = new MyObj(); // call a constructor (parameterless)
var myObjArray = new MyObj[10]; // create an array of 10 MyObjs
var myObj = new MyObj{someProperty="someValue"}; // initializer notation.
```

Note you can mix the array and initializer so you can do this and its legals::

```
var myInts = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6}; //create an int array with 6 values.
```

To fix your snippet you need to add parens like so::

```
   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
```

If you are sending strings of sql I strongly recommend using the library [Dapper-Dot-Net](https://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) found on nuget.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't correctly created your `SqlCommand` instance:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
```

turns into:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from ShoppingList");
```

which in turn means:

```
con.Open("Select * from ShoppingList", con)();
```

becomes simply:

```
con.Open();
```

and similarly with `con.Close();`.